# Volley null request

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

I am trying to change password in the below fragment. But when I enter the values no action is happening. I have 3 fields:
**1.** current_password
**2.** new_password
**3.** re-enter_password.

I am using volley. I tested on debugger the values are null. Only the if condition where `curr_pass.equals("")...` is working. how do I proceed? Below is the entire fragment with initialized views.

```
public class Change_password extends Fragment {
EditText current_pass,new_pass,re_enter_pass;
String curr_pass, newer_pass, re_pass,id;
Button changePwd_btn;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
Session session;
String SP = "Name";
String url = "https://vendorapp.web4rest.com/VendorController/changePassword";
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //returning our layout file
    //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.change_password, container, false);

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    current_pass = v.findViewById(R.id.current_pwd);
    new_pass = v.findViewById(R.id.new_pwd);
    re_enter_pass = v.findViewById(R.id.re_enter_pwd);
    changePwd_btn = v.findViewById(R.id.change_pwd);
    changePass();
    return v;
}

  changePwd_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ConnectivityManager ConnectionManager = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = ConnectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected() == true) {
                curr_pass = current_pass.getText().toString();
                newer_pass = new_pass.getText().toString();
                re_pass = re_enter_pass.getText().toString();

                if (curr_pass.equals("") || newer_pass.equals("") || re_pass.equals("")) {
                    builder.setTitle("Something went wrong!!");
                    displayAlert("Enter valid details");
                }else{

                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(response);
                                        SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SP, MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        id = preferences.getString("ID", null);
                                        if (Integer.parseInt(jobject.getString("status"))==200){
                                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Password changed successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            session.setLoggedin(true);
                                            getActivity().finish();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),jobject.getString("msg"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        Log.e("Error", "Login Failed" + e.toString());
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }){
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> parmams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            parmams.put("curr_pass", curr_pass);
                            parmams.put("new_pass", newer_pass);
                            parmams.put("user_id",id);

                            return parmams;
                        }

                    };
                    MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Network Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Have you initialized the views properly

Comment: @ Ranjan Das: I have edited the code with initialized views

Comment: In this code where it is showing Null Exception

Comment: What you are getting in Log.e("Error", "Login Failed" + e.toString());